# regex doesn't work as expected, not allowed characters at the start and one in all string

Tags: regex

I have the following requirements for string

- not allowed + - and = at the beginning of the field
- vertical slash | is not allowed at all for the word entry
- ignore spaces around the entry

```
^\s*[^\+\-\=|][^|]*\s*$
```

I've written this regex, I expected that it should work, but it doesn't.
I've tried " +a" and it matches,it's incorrect. Removing [^|]* or * from \s*  makes my regex more valid (" +a" not matches regex - it's correct), but I need a full valid regex but not partially valid

Comment: `+a` matched because the space was matched with `[^\+\-\=|]`, maybe you want `^\s*([^\s+=-|])[^|]*\s*$`? That means, another requirement is no whitespace as the first char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  `+a` matched because the space at the start was matched with `[^\+\-\=|]`. This pattern matches any char but `+`, `-`, `=`, and `|`, and thus matches whitespace.

That means, you need another requirement: no whitespace as the first char.

You can use

```js
^\s*[^\s+=-|][^|]*\s*$
```

Note there is no need to escape lots of chars in character classes, and `[^\s+=-|]` matches any one char but whitespace, `+`,`=`, `-` and `|`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RGGTKa/2).